# I need ExitNodes For Kingdom of Saudi Arabia on Tor Browser

Tags: onion-services

I wanna use KSA IP address on exitnodes at Tor Browser. Can anybody locate the KSA Fingerprints for IP.

Need Urgent Reply.

Answer (score 1):

try TO ADD this to the end of Torcc file

```
#-----------------
    #ExitNodes {sa}
    StrictNodes 1
#-----------------
```

you can change "sa" with any country code from this table:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2

Note: middle East Node are operated by innocent inexpert individuals, so the will be too slow, and **in many case** they cannot handle a problems they ma face due to running a tor relay in dictator's  country. so avoid using such exit node for political reason in order not to harm any one.